# mod_rewrite and .htaccess exception to the rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to hide the .php extension throughout my site, I have this snippet and it works fine. However I have one URL that I want to be an exception to the rule, that is I want it have the .php intact and all it's $_GET params.

How can I include that exception into this snippet? And why does it work?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add exception like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule !^(exception1|exception2) %1/ [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

btw this code and comment look like something I would have written it in the past :)

Comment: Outstanding, and while I have the author here, how can I add a trailing slash to the URL?

Comment: check updated code for adding a trailing slash as well.